# Route NotFoundHttpException with css file using Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

In my blade template I have `{!! Html::style('css/style.css') !!}` in my head.

It perfectly renders to `<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/app/css/style.css">`

However, when I try to open the link in the source of the page I get an exception:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Any solution for this? Is it required to specify a different route?

Comment: You just didn't specify the route on the URL you land !

Comment: @Didi you sure you need to make a route for assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, forgot the public directory.

`{!! Html::style('/public/css/style.css') !!}`

Comment: And no need to add anything to the route file ;-)

Comment: okay my bad ! ^^
I use this to include my `.css` files in my `.blade.php` files : `@section('css')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/whatever.css') }}">
@stop`